# Creating "shell object" to submit form params via Change.org API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using the [change-ruby gem](https://github.com/ericisaiah/change-ruby) to take form params and submit them via the Change.org API. I am new to Rails and so I am likely not fully understanding how to properly implement this library and use it in my controller.

I have a form that posts some params to the `#sign` action in `ChangeController`. In this controller I attempt to include the `change-ruby` gem, as well as its resources.

Currently, though, when I submit the form I am given the error: `uninitialized constant Petitions::ChangeController::Petition` on the line where I attempt to create a new Petition object (`petition = Petition.new(client)`). What am I missing?

To be clear, my app uses Engines and this one happens to be called `Petitions`.

`ChangeController` code:

```
# Visit https://github.com/ericisaiah/change-ruby for documentation
require 'change-ruby'

module Petitions

  include Change::Resources

  class ChangeController < ApplicationController

    def sign
      client = Change::Requests::Client.new({ :api_key => ENV["CHANGE_API_KEY"], :secret_token => ENV["CHANGE_SECRET"] })

      # Get the petition (this is where the error occurs)
      petition = Petition.new(client)

      # Get the petition id from the Petition URL
      petition_id = petition.get_id(params[:petition_url][:value])

      # Load the petition
      petition.load(petition_id)

      # Get the petition auth key
      petition.request_auth_key({
        :requester_email => params[:requester_email][:value],
        :source => params[:page_slug][:value],
        :source_description => "Campaign page that is gathering signatures to help the petition."
      })

      # Submit signature
      petition.signatures.add_signature({
        :email => params[:sig_email],
        :first_name => params[:sig_first],
        :last_name => params[:sig_last],
        :address => params[:sig_street],
        :city => params[:sig_city],
        :state_province => params[:sig_state],
        :postal_code => params[:sig_zip],
        :country_code => params[:sig_country],
        :hidden => params[:sig_hidden]
      })
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Are you getting the error on this line? `petition = Petition.new(client)`

Comment: I am. It seems as though the creation of the Client object is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Answer was simple: the `include Change::Resources` line needed to be inside the ChangeController class, otherwise it wasn't accessible to the controller.